# How to train a neural network with inputs of different dimensions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I wanted to design a neural network with inputs and outputs of cell arrays. The inputs are matrices with the same column dimension, but the row dimensions are not with the same dimension.

For example I have two inputs: a 4*4 double and another 5*4 double and the corresponding outputs are a 4*2 double and a 5*2 double. The Matlab error is that the dimensions of rows are not the same when I want to configure the network. However, I can configure and train a feedforward network when I use data with the same row dimension.

My question is how can I create a network in this situation (what type of neural network is good for such dataset?), and how is it possible to combine two or more neural networks?

**Edit** Will it cause a problem to add a row and place "NaN" in the 4*2 matrix and turn it into a 5*2 matrix?
Thank you.

Comment: Definetly  not NaN

Comment: @AnderBiguri Can you explain me why? because when I place another row with "NaN" it does not give me error and it trains.

Comment: It trains properly? NaNs are dangerous, because anything multiplied by NaN will be NaN, so you risk propagating your errors

Comment: @AnderBiguri you're right, is there any other way to overcome this problem? even using another type of network? or combining different neural networks?